# static_assert on reference template argument type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

What I'm trying to do is this simple template clamp function.
I want to ensure `upper >= lower` either in runtime and at compile-time.

```
template <typename T>
T clamp(const T& lower, const T& upper, const T& n)
{
    weak_assert(upper >= lower);
    return std::max(lower, std::min(n, upper));
}
```

It seems reasonable to write:

```
static_assert(upper >= lower, "invalid bounds");
```

However, when called with non-`constexpr` arguments, compiler gives me this:

```
Static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
In instantiation of function template specialization 'clamp<int>' requested here
```

Is there any way to achieve this properly? When called with `constexpr` (say, `clamp<int>(0, 10, myvar)` the static_assert should be fired, otherwise the usual dynamic assert will do?

Comment: You can enforce the constexpr evaluation by using a helper struct with a static value member, and put the static_assert in that. It changes the call signature for constexpr and non-constexpr calls though... I knw of no way to do an optional static_assert, and it would make little sense, as the fact that the evaluation of a constexpr function is actually evaluated at compile time is not specified unless it is used as to set a template parameter.

Comment: Starting with c++14 you are allowed to add assert() to constexpr functions.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with C++14 `assert()` is allowed in constexpr functions, but even with C++11 you can trick it in by using `operator ,`:

```
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
constexpr T clamp(const T& lower, const T& upper, const T& n)
{
    return assert(upper >= lower), std::max(lower, std::min(n, upper));
}
```

Comment: That's a nice trick, however, I use the custom wrapper for `assert` because I need it to write to log and don't call the real `assert` on Android.

Comment: @Hedin In that case you have to use two different functions, one `constexpr` with the `static_assert()` and a runtime function with your `weak_assert()`. I.e. you have to leave it to the user of the functions to decide which one is right.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is right to forbid `static_assert` here because in c++ you can't use function parameters in constexpr context... But to do more or less what you want you could wrap your parameters up in `std::integral_constant` and deduce their values just like you can deduce their type. It can be done e.g. like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, T val>
using ic = std::integral_constant<T, val>;

template <typename T, T lower, T upper>
T clamp(ic<T, lower>, ic<T, upper>, const T& n)
{
    static_assert(upper >= lower, "invalid bounds");
    return std::max(lower, std::min(n, upper));
}

int main() {
    clamp(ic<std::size_t, 5>{},  ic<std::size_t, 10>{}, std::size_t{8});
    // clamp(ic<std::size_t, 10>{},  ic<std::size_t, 5>{}, std::size_t{8}); // static assertion failed: invalid bounds
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/H8IzAEvHRo01julX)